# Page on my site with Facebook Login redirects to Facebook page with error

Tags: facebook

I have this page http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php

It is a test page I made that has a Facebook login button.  For some reason it just started (or I just noticed) to redirect to Facebook with an error page that says nothing but "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Does anyone know how to fix this or what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, fixed it by commenting out some code.  The below code broke things:

```
$feed_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
                . "&message=" . $message;

         if (empty($_REQUEST["post_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $feed_url . "'</script>");
         } else {
            echo ("Feed Post Id: " . $_REQUEST["post_id"]);
         }
```